# .htaccess two query string cannot link to original folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Here is the file structure of my web

css/
script/
images/
.htaccess
index.php
ajaxusername.php

.htaccess content

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?d=$1&t=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?d=$1
```

When input http://www.abc.com/peter/, 
it can translate into http://www.abc.com/index.php?d=peter successfully.
When i input http://www.abc.com/peter/password, 
it can translate into http://www.abc.com/index.php?d=peter&t=password successfully too.

The problem is:
`/peter/` can get the resources listed in above folders successfully but, 
`/peter/password` cannot get those resources. 
When I checked in firebug, it shows me it points to 
http://www.abc.com/peter/css/user.css, 
which is an invalid URL. 

 The correct URL must point to http://www.abc.com/css/user.css instead the previous one.

Any suggestion? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you're using relative paths for css, js and images and once you start using pretty URL scheme of `/part1/part2` it messes up URLs of your resources. As you've noted that css URI becomes `/peter/css/user.css` instead of `/css/user.css`.

Here are some solutions for you to help.

**Solution 1:** To overcome your issue I recommend using **absolute path** in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Solution 2:** It is no doubt better to use absolute path for static files (css, js, images etc). But if you have lots of those instances in several pages then consider using [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to specify a default URL for relative paths. eg:

```
<base href="http://www.abc.com/" />
```

**Solution 3:** mod_rewrite based solution. Use it when you can't implement above solutions.

Have you .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't do anything for a real directory, file or link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule - [L]

# your original rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?d=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?d=$1&t=$2 [QSA,L]

# rules to fix wrong paths of css, js and images
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/((?:css|script|images)/.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I did try solution 1 and it work but not success in solution 3 when i paste the whole code into my htaccess. However, when I just append the last code `RewriteRule ^[^/]+/((?:css|script|images)/.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]` to my htaccess, its work! Really Thanks!!

Comment: Good to know. All 3 solutions actually work but recommended one is of course #1 that you have used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add exceptions to your rewrite rules for requests to files and directories that exist on the server, otherwise when the files are requests by the client's browser they won't be served since the url is rewritten.

Try adding these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
```

into your htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

...put them here...

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?d=$1&t=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?d=$1
```

And your resources should be accessible.